Why does removing <v-app-bar> make the program work properly
I created a new vuetify project, but after I used <v-app-bar>, everything on my page disappeared.
As you can see from F12, there is nothing in <div id="app">:

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts?t=1724891763477"></script>
</body>

main.ts
/**
 * main.ts
 *
 * Bootstraps Vuetify and other plugins then mounts the App`
 */

// Plugins
import { registerPlugins } from '@/plugins'

// Components
import App from './App.vue'

// Composables
import { createApp } from 'vue'

// vue router
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)

registerPlugins(app)

app.mount('#app')

App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
// import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
</script>

<template>
  <header>
    <v-app-bar>
    </v-app-bar>
  </header>

  <RouterView />
</template>

router/index.ts
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import('../views/AboutView.vue')
    }
  ]
})

export default router

Both HomeView and AboutView display only one sentence.
If you delete <v-app-bar>, the information will be displayed.
App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
// import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
</script>

<template>
  <header>
  </header>

  <RouterView />
</template>

Now you can see something from F12:

<body>
    <div id="app" data-v-app=""><header></header><main> This is HomeView. <a href="/about" class="">about</a></main></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts?t=1724811523937"></script>
</body>


How did you generate your project? That's definitely not what I'd expect to see in your index.html since browser's cannot directly run TypeScript

Any console errors?

The question requires https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please, provide a way to reproduce

V-app-bar should be a child of v-app (or v-layout if it is not a full-page layout), but it seems to be missing in your code. A missing layout will cause other errors too. If you add v-app, does it work?

Forgot to add: typically, the page content goes into `v-main', checkout the layout docs.
